# Javascript - Styling a Div's background

Tags: javascript, css, styles, background-image

I have some javascript that changes a divs background on hover (over a button) , but I am having trouble making the image that loads center and cover the div

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
function link01() {
    document.getElementById("hover-change").style.backgroundImage =
 "url(images/w1.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat";
}
```

Button:

```
       <div class="open-project-link">
    <a onmouseover="link01(this)" style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px;"
 class="open-project" href="project3.html">Bowman Clay</a>
    </div>
```

Div:

```
<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change" 
style="background-image: url(images/w0.jpg);">
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

It should be a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Please include the CSS & HTML structure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the shorthand for **background** with `style.backgroundImage`, that is invalid. Instead use just `style.background` :

```js
function link01() {
  document.getElementById("hover-change").style.background =
    "url(http://placekitten.com/300) no-repeat center / cover"
}
```

```css
#hover-change {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-project-link">
  <a onmouseover="link01(this)" style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px;" class="open-project" href="project3.html">Bowman Clay</a>
</div>
Div:

<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change" style="background-image: url(images/w0.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChrisLad I've removed the function `link01` to make the snippet, but you need to keep it on your actual code

Comment: Yes I saw still seems to break the hover I'd updated my question with the full code etc

Comment: My bad I forgot the /

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `background-position`, `background-repeat` with `style.backgroundImage`.

Instead try it with `style.background`

```
function link01() {
    document.getElementById("hover-change").style.background =
 "url(images/w1.jpg) no-repeat center / cover";
}
```

Comment: @DaniP Corrected it. Thanks for the info.